# VBA html tag text query without inner tag

Tags: xml, vba, dom

There's such html:

```
<h1 class="title">NOW ZINC PICOLINATE 50MG 60caps CYNK PIKOLINIAN
  <small>(6826446676)</small>
</h1>
```

I want to get only this: *"NOW ZINC PICOLINATE 50MG 60caps CYNK PIKOLINIAN"*

When I use:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
```

I get: *"NOW ZINC PICOLINATE 50MG 60caps CYNK PIKOLINIAN (6826446676)"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).childNodes(0).nodeValue
'                                         /|\
'        All nodes, including #text -------|
```